# Button on Table View Cell connected to local function

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a table view cell which is loaded with data from a Parse request. It essentially loads "friend requests", showing the requesting friends name and two buttons, "Accept" and "Reject"

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath func:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:Notifications_JLR_Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! Notifications_JLR_Cell

    cell.txtRequestDesc.text = searchResults[indexPath.row].requesteeName + " has requested to be your friend"

    cell.btnApprove_outlet.addTarget(self, action:Selector("approve"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

The table loads fine, and the addTarget line, once the "Approve" button is clicked, runs the func:

```
func approve() {
    println("approve")
}
```

However, when I am fetching my Parse data, I have set in an array, the objectId for the friend request, which I want to refer to in the approve() function

How can I pass the objectId string thats saved in my array to the approve() function when there is no "withObject" parameter in addTarget ?

I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787676/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-table-view-cell-in-ios?rq=1) but that suggests adding the two button programatically, which I don't really want to do because I then have to programatically deal with the button constraints, which is a pain if I can just somewhere pass a parameter to my approve() function

(I cannot use .tag because that only accepts integers)

Comment: What information do you need to get objectid from your array? You could pass the tag of the cell and retrieve it from that. Alternatively you could extend the cell class and add a parameter called objectid and retrieve it from the sender.

Comment: Good thinking.. Thanks for the push in the right direction... I got where I needed by setting the buttons tag to the indexPath.row and then calling "approve:" with the following code: 
`code`    
func approve(sender: UIButton) {
        let test:String = searchResults[sender.tag].objectId
        println("objectId= \\(test)")
}
`code`

Not sure if I can mark the above as answered or not ? Perhaps a mod could verify ?